# How can I deploy my application code which should be accessible only to me and the websever and not any other admins/users?

Tags: python, django, iis, obfuscation

I have my application code which I have to host on my client's on premises machine.
The code should not be visible to any admin/user other than me(I am an admin).
I host it on IIS. I want to know how the code can be accessible to me and IIS and no one else using the machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to hire a security professional to assist on hardening this machine. There are many to do, like removing all other administrators, and you shouldn't expect a site like this is a the right place.

Comment: If this client has paid you for this code it is unethical do try and hide it away from them or make it unreadable- you'll not always be around and they may need a future dev to work on it.

Comment: No the client is not paying for the code,  it is our intellectual property @Nealium

Comment: The server is an on prem one and the code is out intellectual property so we don't want it to be exposed to other users/admins on the machine. Every deployment to the application is done by us. @LexLi

Comment: you mean accessible with your specific device or from user creds?

Comment: With my admin creds @HemalPatel

Comment: maybe you can create custom middleware from which every request passes and depending on the user you can permit it if it's admin else you can render a static page mentioning you don't have permission.

Comment: The client is also an admin on the machine, they are using our services, so we don't want to risk exposing our code to the client. The application is hosted on the server and is accessible to all the devices in the client network on their browsers. No restriction needed at application level. The code which is fed to IIS should not be open and readable for any person opening it. @HemalPatel

Comment: Set strict file permissions on code files to further restrict access. Grant read and execute permissions only to your user account and the IIS service account. Remove all other permissions, including those for the customer administrator account.

Comment: Being an admin if I'm able to change the file permissions of the code files, customer admin account can also change it and give access to themselves @YurongDai

Comment: Consider encrypting the code itself. This will make it difficult for unauthorized users (including other administrators) to access and understand the code, even if they gain access to the file. Alternatively, instead of deploying the entire code base on a single server, spread the application components across multiple servers or containers. This way no single entity has full access to the entire codebase.